# Simple online database

Tags: sql, database-server

I am not an expert in servers or databases, but I have the following question.

I want to create a database online, containing basic data, that is needed for my app. I don't want to write to the database from the app at all, but read from it.

Is there any service where I can build a database online, simply without programmatic code. I am looking for a service that basically will be like excel, easy to make some tables with values, easy to change data when necessary. All the dealing with the database can be online, in a easy interface. I just need to request the data from the app, and it will be sent from the server as a json or something.

Is there any service like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task with the help of **phpMyAdmin**.

Nowadays, most web hosting providers also provide service for database hosting service.

Whenever you choose a website hosting service, you can make a database from their `cPanel` and then handle it using phpMyAdmin. This tool lets you configure your databse properly with the **GUI functions**.

Comment: then please up vote my answer and mark it as accepted